# Designing the flow of OAuth2 authentication

Tags: java, spring, oauth-2.0, spring-security-oauth2

I am trying to come up with a proper OAuth2 authentication flow for a parent/child relationship.
App-A and App-B are two independent applications. `App-A` opens up `App-B` in an iframe when clicks on a link from `App-A`.

I am responsible for maintaining `App-B`.
How can I design the flow in a way so that `App-B` recognizes users coming from `App-A` and keep the same session across both the applications?

This is the flow I have come up with so far:

1. `App-A` will provide a client-id and secret-key to `App-B` before the interaction.
2. User makes a request to `GET /person` endpoint of `App-B` with a `parentId`.
3. `App-B` will then sends a request to `App-A` server with client-id, secret-key and `redirect-url` set as `GET /person`.

Now what `App-A` will send to `App-B` to pass the session info of authenticated user.

If the flow doesn't make sense, you can get rid of it

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is similar to maintaining session in multiple apps.

The problem with your approach is you need make that request from front end or some
Way to AppA (which maintains current user session) which exposes client id/secret

Here is some ideas you could achieve it,

**Is both application is under same parent domain?** if so,

Like **appA.domain.com** and **appB.domain.com**
  Then after successful authentication, you can set some session identifier cookie in parent domain ***..domain.com**
 Then from appB you can get the get the current user session from which you can get the accessToken too.

**If both applications are in different domain**, then

you need to have some common auth server which will maintain session commonly , so when appA loads and found no session available , then it can redirect to common auth server , which in turns check session ( if not let user login ) then send the data back to appA

The same flow goes for appB.

Also check this link
http://merbist.com/2012/04/04/building-and-implementing-a-single-sign-on-solution/